# On iOS 8 how do you access hi-res photos when you have the optimize photos on?

Tags: ios, icloud, photos.app, photos

I the iOS 8 beta 5 they introduced the new option option, Optimize iPhone Storage keeps lower resolution copies of photos on device, and stores original high-res photos in iCloud.

How do you access the hi-res photos when you need them?